# NGINX Configuration issue

Tags: nginx, configuration, virtualhost

I have a issue with my nginx configuration. The problem is that it always use the proxy conf it never use the beta.node365-p.se conf.

I want that if the requested domain is beta.node365-p.se the server should handel it locally but if the request is for something else it should proxy it to the other apache server.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name  beta.node365-p.se;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name "";

    location / {
            proxy_buffers 16 4k;
            proxy_buffer_size 2k;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://31.44.238.211:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be only one default_server

Comment: @AlexeyTen Thanks! But it didn't help. Now it is revers everything is going to the local server nothing goes to proxy.

Comment: You have to use the `default_server` directive on the virtual server where you have the proxy define. On the first virtual server (beta...) you must not have `default_server`.

Comment: I changed that but it didn't help :/ all sites go to local  @TeroKilkanen

Comment: So, what is the full configuration you tried last, and how did you test that it did not work right?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I tested by visiting this sites http://beta.node365-p.se and http://node365-p.se. If the proxy works it should show apache message. The full config now is: [link](http://pastebin.com/cXvpzj8N)

Comment: You could try adding `debug_connection <your IP address>;` to `nginx.conf` `events` section, then restart nginx and load the page. This way you will get detailed output to nginx error log, and that can be used to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Here is the result of debug_connection. @TeroKilkanen 
when accessing from http://node365-p.se the result is :[link](http://pastebin.com/BgacyK7t)
when accessing from http://beta.node365-p.se the result is:[link](http://pastebin.com/4RYxNSE7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `server_name "";` by `server_name _;` and let `default_server` options in the second vhost only.

The first server_name case means you match request without Host directive (i.e. HTTP/1.0 requests).
The second means you match a wildcard server name choosen as a second option if other vhost don't contain the right server_name considering the Host header of the initial request.

**Update** :

- Your conf is missing listen directives in vhosts.
- You are not passing the right Host header while proxying, change `proxy_set_header Host $host;` by `proxy_set_header Host "beta.node365-p.se";`.

Comment: It didn't help. the current config is http://pastebin.com/4m1rdJGm

Comment: @qarek Post your full config so. Nginx.conf + all vhosts. BTW, You don't have listen directives in your config !

Comment: The nginx.conf = http://pastebin.com/xYSaWKkR and my only vhost= pastebin.com/4m1rdJGm. @XavierLucas

Comment: @qarek You don't have listen directives in your vhosts !

Comment: It works now @XavierLucas